# React i18next-http-backend won't load translation json file from Public folder

Tags: reactjs

I have React app in which I am trying to get language options set up using i18next http backend. However it seems that when the call is made to get the json file it is not returned correctly.

My json files are stored in the Public folder in a subfolder locales and the call to fetch these is made:

```
backend: {
    loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json",
},
```

Looking at the network tab I am getting 200:

[image]

But if I put that URL directly into the browser I get the app navbar and an empty page as if it is loading an instance of the app, rather than grabbing the json file.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by creating a .env file in the root of the project and adding the line PUBLIC_URL=*sub_folder* where subfolder was where my app was.